# How to select where sum of fields is greater than a value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Using MongoDB, How would I write this regular SQL statement?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1+field2+field3) > 1
```

I've been messing with $group, $project, $add, etc. I feel like I'm dancing all around the solution but can't figure it out.

Comment: do you need to perform this query often or is this one time shot?

Comment: Let's say its a one-time shot, but I'd be interested in seeing either solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) (I am not telling that it is not possible to do this with aggregation)

```
db.table.find({$where: function() {
   return this.field1 + this.field2 + this.field3 > 1
   // most probably you have to handle additional cases if some of the fields do not exist.
}}
```

The pros of it is that it is easy and intuitive, whereas cons:

> requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or
>   function for each document in the collection.

If you need to perform this kind of searches often, I would go ahead and create a new field which will have a sum of 3 fields stored in it and put an index on it. The downside is that you have to increase your app logic.

Comment: Yes, I keep forgetting I can put javascript in there

Answer (score 5):

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 1, "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 2 })
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "sum" : { "$add" : ["$a", "$b", "$c" ] } 
    } }, 
    { "$match" : { 
        "sum" : { "$gte" : 4 } 
    } }
])
{ "_id" : 1, "sum" : 4 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an old post but this might help someone looking for other solutions. I found this to be even simpler than both `$where` and `.aggregate()`.

```
> db.foo.insert({"a": 17, "b": 8})
> db.foo.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$add: ["$a", "$b"]}, 25]}})   // no result
> db.foo.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$add: ["$a", "$b"]}, 24]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("602acf55a69fb564c11af7db"), "a" : 17, "b" : 8 }
```