# Retrieve Documents where sum of sizes of arrays is greater than given value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongoose Schema defined as such:

```
const hackathonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hackathonId: {type: Number, required: true},
    uuid: {type: String, required: true},
    data: {type: Object, required: true},
    isPublished: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    organisers: [String],
    volunteers: [String],
    participants: [String],
    mentors: [String]
});

export default mongoose.model('Hackathon', hackathonSchema);
```

I want to retrieve all the Hackathons where the 
length of:

```
( organisers + volunteers + participants +mentors ) >= 500
```

or any value for that matter.

I found an answer of SO that does this but not in Mongoose [How to select where sum of fields is greater than a value in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860348/how-to-select-where-sum-of-fields-is-greater-than-a-value-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the sizes together:

With MongoDB 3.4 or greater using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/)

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$size": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              { "$ifNull": [ "$organisers", [] ]  },
              { "$ifNull": [ "$volunteers", [] ]  },
              { "$ifNull"; [ "$participants", [] ] },
              { "$ifNull": [ "$mentors", [] ] }
            ]
          } },
          500
        ]    
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
],function(err,results) { 

})
```

Or in earlier versions without that operator

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$add": [
            { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$organisers", [] ] } },
            { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$volunteers", [] ] } },
            { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$participants", [] ] } },
            { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$mentors", [] ] } }
          ]},
          500
        ]    
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
],function(err,results) { 

})
```

In either approach you are using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as a logical filter for the documents in the collection. As a native operator, this is the fastest way you can process this condition.

Internally it's only argument is [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) which is a "ternary" operation ( if/then/else ) to evaluate and return a value. So when the result of the condition to `"if"` results in `true`, `"then"` the action is to `$$KEEP` the document, or alternately `"else"` to `$$PRUNE` the document from the results.

The differing approaches based on versions are either:

- [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays) in order to make one "big" array and return it's [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)
- Or use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) on each array and [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) the values to get a total.

As for just returning the `_id` field only, then it is a simple matter of adding a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage, where just like in regular query projection, you provide the list of properties to return. In this case, only the `_id` field.

You could add some presumptions as to the minimum array length to the base query with a `$match` first, but this would be a presumption, rather than absolute fact.

---

For the record, you can run exactly the same thing using the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause, but since this operator uses JavaScript evaluation rather than being natively implemented as the aggregation framework operations are, then it does make a significant performance impact in that it runs slower:

```
Model.find({ "$where": function() {
   return [
     ...this.organisers,
     ...this.volunteers,
     ...this.participants,
     ...this.mentors
   ].length > 500
}).select({ "_id": 1 }).exec(function(err,results) {
})
```

So whilst it may "look pretty" compared to the DSL form of an aggregation pipeline structure, the performance penalty is not really worth it. You should only do this if your MongoDB version lacks [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as an operator, which would be prior to MongoDB 2.6. And in that case, you should probably be updating MongoDB for other reasons as well.

Comment: What does the 'redact' operator achieve here? I'm able to make sense of the rest!

Comment: @bholagabbar There is a link. And I was actually adding the explanation whilst you were typing.

Comment: Now if I just wanted to retrieve only a list the Hackathon Ids `id` instead of the entire models, how would this query be modified? If it were a `find()` query I would do it something like `find({id}, ...query)`; would it be the same here too?

Comment: @bholagabbar Added. Probably a good exercise for you to become acquainted with the [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation). Working with MongoDB, you are going to need to know how to use these.